# the way to set grant option is given by role

Tags: postgresql, sql-grant

I am using a postgresql.

My goal is that grant option should be granted by role
According to Recommendation document said that I have to remove 'public' grantee

When I typed

```
SELECT grantee, privilege_type 
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
group by grantee, privilege_type;
```

I got a screenshot what I have done.

[image]

To sum up, I want to hide these 2 marked lines. or try not to show up in that query sentence.

what should I do?

p.s I already had used:

```
revoke update, select on information_schema.role_table_grants from public;
```

but nothing changed!

Comment: Your select does not include the table for which the privileges were granted, so to me it doesn't really make sense (and the group by in that query is completely useless) . If you want to remove select privilege from a specific table then you should `revoke` the privs from **that** table, not from information_schema views.

Comment: ah I got it. information_schema is a read only Thanks.